# Pycharm Django Project using Vagrant Server: Error Package requirements are not satisfied

Tags: django, pycharm, vagrant

I am trying to start a Django Project using Vagrant and PyCharm Professional edition. I am using a Windows computer and my Vagrant file looks like this https://gist.github.com/LondonAppDev/d990ab5354673582c35df1ee277d6c24

Below is my project just in case (not really required to answer this question )
https://github.com/samirtendulkar/profiles-rest-api

Now through Pycharm Terminal I added

```
vagrant init
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/$ mkvirtualenv profiles_app_venv --python=python3
(profiles_app_venv) vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/$ pip install django==1.11
(profiles_app_venv) vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/$ pip install djangorestframework==3.6.2
```

Then I added a `src` folder in my root project and started making another app

Then I created a requirements.txt

```
(name_of_env) vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant/$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

See Image below. **I know that this is because my project in running on my Vagrant server and my Pycharm is running on my host server. But I am losing out on all of Pycharm's best features. How can I override this**

[image]

Any Idea What I need to do here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to override anything. The problem is that you included a requirements.txt file without setting your project interpreter.  What you should do is go to `Settings > Project > Project Interpreter`, and choose your project interpreter to be the path where `profiles_app_venv` lives on your local server.  A few seconds after applying this (or immediately if you restart PyCharm), you should see those warnings go away as it recognizes that they are installed in your chosen interpreter.

Comment: I don't know how to find `profiles_app_venv` its in the vagrant file

Comment: I have added a image above. I even tried clicking on vagrant but it does not do anything

Comment: Thanks buddy the restarting Pycharm it seems was important

Comment: glad you were able to figure it out with my `meh` directions :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

- Ensure all the packages are listed in Project Interpreter settings.
- In PyCharm, go to File | Invalidate Caches/Restart
- Click on Invalidate and Restart.
- Wait for IDE to finish updating.

You should be good as long as you are pointing to the correct interpreter and the packages are in the interpreter